# java.lang.VerifyError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name in java cxf web service client

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf

Could any help me with this issue? I'm gettin the following error trace when I try to get a response from a SOAP web service:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoBase.<clinit>(CryptoBase.java:71)
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:945)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadSignatureCrypto(WSHandler.java:863)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor.access$100(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:54)
```

I think that's related with some problem on the pom.xml file, I'm using apache.cxf 3.1.11 version:

```
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
and apacheCommons 3.5 version
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
```

The project has also:

```
<spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-framework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
<spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be util for someone, I was using two versions of the same library on my project: bcprov-jdk15on and bcprov-jdk14on.

-bcprov-jdk15on included in cxf-rt-ws-security
and
-bcprov-jdk14on included in iText/jasperreports

The solution was just to ommit bcprov-jdk14on from my pom.xml 'cause actually I don't need it